# Does the .git directory hold remote passwords or SSH keys?

Tags: git, ssh-keys, tortoisegit

I have my Git project in a Dropbox public folder, including the `.git` directory. I have my SSH key saved in TortoiseGit which I use for committing and pushing to GitHub. Are these saved elsewhere, or are the SSH keys and/or passwords stored inside the `.git` directory which could potentially be accessed by anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ssh keys shouldn't be in a `.git` folder at all.

By default, they are in `~/.ssh` (or, on Widows, where `%HOME%` is defined).
Or in an application path managed by TortoiseGit.

But those keys aren't specific to a given Git repo, and are never stored within a `.git` folder.

Comment: I assume this is also true for password authentication? (I actually don't remember if TortoiseGit even saves that or not)

Comment: @Keavon yes, it is saved outside of the .git folder: it is an application feature managed by TortoiseGit.